# upload file in gravity forms wordpress - scroll page not working

Tags: javascript, wordpress, file-upload, scroll, gravity-forms-plugin

After I upload multiple images in the file upload field I can't scroll past them to the Submit button or to the rest of the page. How can that be fixed?